# E: Unable to locate package sun-java5-jre

Tags: установка, java, debian

Думаю, понятно: при установке java5 появляется данная ошибка. OC debian.

```
user321:~# apt-get install -y sun-java5-jreReading package lists... DoneBuilding dependency treeReading state information... DoneE: Unable to locate package sun-java5-jre
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас Debian Lenni, то это должно сработать (на примере JDK)

```
sudo -iexport "deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ lenny main non-freedeb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ lenny main non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.listexport "deb http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main non-freedeb-src http://security.debian.org/ lenny/updates main non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.listapt-get updateapt-get install sun-java5-jdk
```

Если не Lenni, могут быть проблемы.